# Why is the nutritive value of grass to humans compared to alternatives?

Tags: nutrition

Cows thrive on eating large amounts of grass. That's because they have specialized digestive processes, such as [chewing a cud](https://www.usdairy.com/news-articles/why-do-cows-chew-their-cud#:%7E:text=This%20softened%20food%20is%20called,stomach%20to%20be%20fully%20digested.&text=Cud%2Dchewing%20cows%20are%20generally,diet%20and%20produce%20more%20milk.) that maximizes the value of grass to her. Humans who don't have these processes, don't get as much a of a benefit.

Suppose a human being were "stuck" for food, and the most available food was grass. What percentage of the nutritive value of the grass would the human obtain, compared to what the cow would obtain? Also, how would the nutritional value of grass (for humans) compare to vegetables such as lettuce or spinach? And is the lack of nutritional value of grass one reason why humans prefer to eat beef rather than grass, even though 90% or so of energy is lost at every level of the food chain?

Comment: 1. Grass has high silica contents. Chewing it would ruin your teeth. 2. We can't digest the cellulose and hemicellulose that are the major components of grass. Of most nutritional value would be the non-structural carbohydrates and sugars in grass. Their content depends on grass species, fertilization, environmental conditions, age, ... However, we are ill-equipped for extracting these sugars. The most probable outcome of eating larger quantities of grass is vomiting (which would make you lose nutrients in an emergency situation).

Comment: The exception would be sugarcane, which you could chew to extract the sugar.

Comment: Also, consider that cows do not much else than eating grass and digesting it, because this process is not very efficient. Human brains also need much more energy than cow brains. I don't think we could afford that and our usual level of activity if we were ruminants.